# Possible Web App Database Performance Issue

Tags: php, database, web-applications, database-performance

I'm working on an app for personal trainers at gyms to track their client's workouts. The way it works essentially breaks down into two groups.

There are exercises, which are pretty straightforward, just the name, description, sets, reps, and weight. And then there are Programs, which are a set of exercises that the trainer assigns to a client.

Once the trainer assigns a program, he picks a start and end date, and that's what shows up for the client. So say the trainer assigns a program with exercises A, B, and C from 4/8 to 4/13. The goal is to let the client mark off each exercise each day to track what they did. So they might do just exercises A and C on 4/9, but do all 3 on 4/10.

The issue I'm having is that means that it will have to write a row for each exercise, each day, for each client, which can add up to a lot of rows when the number of trainers/clients grows.

The developers I'm working with are worried that it might cause performance issues, but to make a long story short, it's also very possible that they're making up issues to charge more time/hours.

They asked ME if I have a solution, and so I asked a few friends who don't seem to think it would cause an issue.

So yeah, a VERY long winded description all to ask if you think something like that would be an issue for a web app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. First up I call this type of problem a "nice-to-have" in that, if you end up with the problem then (assuming that you are charging for use of the service), you've already won!
Modern relational databases, with proper indexes, can deal with millions of rows data without issue.  I suspect your developers are scamming you or don't know what they're doing.  Also any professional in any field shouldn't be asking a layman for solutions.  Here's what I'd do:
1) Ask them to list the queries they're planning on using, the table structure and any indices.  Post these up here and someone will easily be able to point out any obvious flaws in what they've done
2) Ask them to populate the tables with test rows to the quantity that you would consider to be high.  Get them to profile their queries.  If they give you any hassle, walk away.

Comment: Never attribute to malice that which is adequately explained by stupidity.

Comment: @JoeFrambach Indeed! Good catch.

Comment: I agree, it would be a nice problem to have! Thanks for your detailed response/suggestions. I'm going to suggest this and see what they say. I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

No, you can easily handle 100k's of rows.

The database schema must be well designed, all tables correctly indexed.
Using InnoDB as storage engine is a good option because of the foreign key support that can save you some headaches to maintain the table integrity (Ie. a client is deleted then all his exercises might be deleted.)

Implement pagination on all pages to avoid displaying too many rows.